# What kind of formula is used to calculate the p-value in `t.test`?

Tags: r, formula, p-value

So, just a touch of backstory. I've been learning biostatistics in the past 4-5 months in university, 6 months of biomathematics before that. I only started deep diving into programming around 5 days ago.
I've been trying to redo `t.test()` with my own function.

```r
test2 = function(t,u){
  T = (mean(t) - u) / ( sd(t) / sqrt(length(t)))
  t1=round(T, digits=5)
  df=length(t)
  cat(paste('t - value =', t1,
  '\n','df =', df-1, 
      '\n','Alternative hipotézis: a minta átlag nem egyenlő a hipotetikus átlaggal'))
}
```

I tried searching the formula for the p-value, I found one, but when I used it, my value was different from the one within the t.test.
The t-value and the df do match `t.test()`.
I highly appreciate any help, thank you.
P.s: Don't worry about the last line, it's in Hungarian.

Comment: The way you can inspect the body (containing the code) of a function varies (see `?methods`). In this case `getS3method("t.test", "default")` reveals the code.

Comment: can you post a link to the formula for the p-value that you found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p-value can be derived from the probability function of the t distribution `pt`. Using this and making the notation more common with sample `x` and population mean `mu` we can use something like:

```r
test2 <- function(x, u){
  t   <- (mean(x) - u) / (sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)))
  df  <- length(x) - 1
  cat('t-value =', t, ', df =', df, ', p =', 2 * (1 - pt(q=t, df=df)), '\n')
}

set.seed(123) # remove this for other random values

## random sample
x <- rnorm(10, mean=5.5)

## population mean
mu <- 5

## own function
test2(x, mu)

## one sample t-test from R
t.test(x, mu=mu)
```

We get for the own `test2`:

```
t-value = 1.905175 , df = 9, p = 0.08914715
```

and for R's `t.test`

```
    One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 1.9052, df = 9, p-value = 0.08915
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 5
95 percent confidence interval:
 4.892330 6.256922
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 5.574626
```

Answer (score 1):

The definitive source of what R is doing is the source code.  If you look at the source code for `stats:::t.test.default` (which you can get by typing `stats:::t.test.default` into the console, without parentheses at the end and hitting enter), you'll see that for a single-sample test like the one you're trying to do above, you would get the following:

```r
  nx <- length(x)
  mx <- mean(x)
  vx <- var(x)
  df <- nx - 1
  stderr <- sqrt(vx/nx)
  tstat <- (mx - mu)/stderr
  if (alternative == "less") {
    pval <- pt(tstat, df)
  }
  else if (alternative == "greater") {
    pval <- pt(tstat, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
  }
  else {
    pval <- 2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
  }
```

These are the relevant pieces (there's a lot more code in there, too).

Comment: May be worth noting that `pt()` is the cumulative distribution of the t-distribution (so `pt(-abs(tstat))` gives the lower tail probability for the two-tailed test). There is no way to write a *simple* formula for this computation (you can find the R code for this too, but it immediately goes into complex C code). There might be some *approximate* formula, but I doubt it -- people used printed look-up tables for this calculation in the Old Days, which they wouldn't have done if there were some reasonably simple approximation available.